# Pyspark - a simple solution to fairly launch jobs trough looping a list of dfs?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

If I do something around the following in python with pyspark `DataFrames` (`df`s):

```py
dfs_list = [df1, df2, df3]

dfs_list_with_transformation = [df.transform(...) for df in dfs_list]

for df in dfs_list_with_transformation:
    df.show() # or any other action
```

The jobs will be launched sequentially ([even in fair scheduler mode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#fair-scheduler-pools)).
An example of a lot of dfs:
[image]

In scala, we can simply do something like:

```scala
dfs_list_with_transformation.par.foreach(df => df.show())
```

**I am not comparing languages, I am just searching for a similarly simple solution. Or at least, a simple way to parallelize a collection loop in python without much code bloat to launch spark jobs/actions taking advantage of spark fair scheduler mode.**

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In the Scala version a [parallel list](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/overview.html) is created by using `.par`. This means that multiple threads in the Spark driver are simultaneously submitting jobs to the Spark cluster without waiting for the previous job (which was submitted by another thread) has finished.

To achieve the same effect in Python we can use a [Threadpool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html):

```python
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
pool = ThreadPool()
pool.map(lambda df:df.show(), dfs_list_with_transformation)
```